# Toggle the <TR>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to do hide the belonging rows. For example if you click on 'Sub Title 1' which will then hide Item 1, Item 2 and Item 3 rows only.

Example:

```
<table border="1">
 <tbody>
  <tr class="head">
   <td> title </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="sub-title">
     <td>Sub Title 1</td>
  </tr>
   <tr> <td>Item 1</td> </tr>
   <tr> <td>Item 2</td> </tr>
   <tr> <td>Item 3</td> </tr>
   <tr class="sub-title">
     <td>Sub Title 2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr> <td>Item 4</td> </tr>
   <tr> <td>Item 5</td> </tr>
   <tr> <td>Item 6</td> </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

-

```
$('.sub-title').click( function() {
    $(this).parent().nextUntil('.sub-title').toggle();
})
```

It doesn't seem to work...

Comment: unfortunately, you cannot modify `tr` elements like this unless you change their `display` property... but I wouldn't recommend this ;-)

Comment: I agree with @ahren, and furthermore `.click()` isn't a good practice, you should use `.on('click')` instead. Did you realize there is a missing semi-colon on JQuery statement?

Comment: The jQuery documentation (http://api.jquery.com/on/) says there is no difference between .Click() and .on('click') http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122078/difference-between-onclick-vs-click

Comment: What I am trying to do hide the belonging rows. For example if you click on 'Sub Title 1' which will then hide Item 1, Item 2, Item 3 rows..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nextUntil selects for siblings, not children. Remove the "parent" from your call.

Edited to respond to further question about excluding some rows based on class. Obviously you can also accommodate Kolink's response about preventing toggle's "display: block" overwriting the default "display: table-row", but as long as you test in all supported browsers, I don't see any problem with using toggle.

```
$('.sub-title').click( function() {
   $(this).nextUntil('.sub-title').each(function() {
        if (!$(this).hasClass('order')) 
            $(this).toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks ...that seem to work.. Just last question - if any tr have 'order' class name then don't hide it.. How to do this?

Comment: Example: `if (!$(this).hasClass('order')) { }`

Comment: Oh, I got it to work `$(this).nextUntil('.sub-title').not('order').toggle();`

Answer (score 1):

You have to toggle manually:

```
$(".sub-title").on("click",function() {
    $(this).nextUntil(".sub-title").each(function() {
        this.style.display = this.style.display == "none" ? "" : "none";
    });
});
```